# How to use IF condition in mysql query

Tags: mysql, hibernate

Problem is simple,but it seems that each time I do something wrong in the mysql syntax.
   I want to search in a table after a String field. If this field exists, I will increase the number of apparitions.If does not exists, I will add a new row with it.
  I am trying to write a query which I will be used with jdbc or hibernate.
  I look at many examples in the site, but I fink that I am doing something wrong in the mysql syntax.

```
For the table:

mysql> select * from phrase;
+----+---------------+-------------------+
| id | phrase_string | apparition_number |
+----+---------------+-------------------+
|  1 | phrase 1      |                 2 |
|  2 | phrase 2      |                 1 |
|  3 | phrase 3      |                 5 |
|  4 | phrase 4      |                 6 |
+----+---------------+-------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I use the IF condition from the MYSQL tutorial:
IF search_condition THEN statement_list
    [ELSEIF search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END IF

So my query looks like:

```
    **mysql> IF SELECT * FROM phrase WHERE phrase_string="phrase 1" THEN
        -> UPDATE phrase SET apparition_number=apparition_number+1
        -> ELSE
        -> INSERT INTO phrase VALUES(NULL,"phrase 1",1)
        -> END IF;**

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF SELECT * FROM phrase WHERE phrase_string="
phrase 1" THEN
UPDATE phrase SET ap' at line 1
```

Can somebody tell me where I am wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: that if clause is not valid as part of a select. just write two statements one for the update ( with a where clause ) and one for the insert ( again with where )

Answer (score 1):

The if [syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html) could be used only as part of stored procedure.

For this use case [insert on duplicate key update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) can be used. Have a look at [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/93aca/1) SQL Fiddle.